# Typescript type for querySelectorAll

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

Due to programming and magic my editor (vscode) knows which type `querySelectorAll` returns if I let Typescript do the typing for me.

But describing below variable `compiled`'s type manually, is too complex for me to comprehend.
How can I explicitly describe its type?

---

In [jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/)/[angular](https://angular.io/) I can (abbreviated):

```
const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Proxy);
const component = fixture.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges();
const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement; // Magic does its work and type is known.

const titleElement = compiled.querySelectorAll('h3'); // Hovering pointer over method returns the type.
expect(titleElement.innerText).toBe('a title');
```

But due to reasons (how jasmine/angular sets up tests with `forEach`) I must declare `compiled` beforehand. Presently I declare it `let compiled: any;` which makes Typescript lose all type knowledge.

```
let compiled: any; // <- this is the variable I want to type.

const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Proxy);
const component = fixture.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges();
compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;

const titleElement = compiled.querySelectorAll('h3')[0]; // Hovering does not yield type.
expect(titleElement.innerText).toBe('a title');
```

Comment: Maybe just `Element`?

Comment: @David Nope. Because `compiled.querySelectorAll('h3')` and
 `compiled.querySelectorAll('div.textContent')` are not of thesame type(!) It works for `h3` but not `div.textContent`. With that said I could `compiled.querySelectorAll('div')[0].textContent-ish` but then I would miss out on the ability to do the `div.textContent` query.

Comment: Sorry, why would they not be the same type?

Comment: @David `querySelectorAll('h3')` is of type `querySelectorAll<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(selectors: K): NodeListOf<HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]>` while `querySelectorAll('div.textContent')` is of type `querySelectorAll<E extends Element = Element>(selectors: string): NodeListOf<E>`.

Comment: @David Delving further in I understand it is due to Typescript's fantastic type system where even different strings can be type-ish. So `querySelectorAll('h3')` uses a known string `h3` and returns one type. While `"div.textContent"` in the latter example is not known and returns a more generic type. I understand the mechanics behind it but am still not sure of how, if even possible, to set the type of my `compiled` variable.

Comment: How did you see these types? And anyway you could  You could also try to cast : `compiled.querySelectorAll<Element>('h3')` and `compiled.querySelectorAll<Element>('div.textcontent')` should both return `NodeListOf<Element>`

Comment: @David I cannot `compiled.querySelectorAll<Element>('div.textcontent').innerText` but I can `compiled.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('div.textcontent').InnerText`. It solves the intellisense problem but stops me from using the same code on SVG or a html-node-ish element. I find the type by pressing F12 on `compiled` when its type is `Element`.

Comment: So you can declare `compiled` as `Element` and dynamically cast `getQuerySelectorAll<YourType>` depending on your needs?

Comment: @David I have only tried `<Element>` and `<HTMLElement>` where the former failed and the latter succeeded.

Comment: Ok, but what I'mm saying is that the type of `compiled` and the type returned by `querySelectorAll` are independant. So you juste declaring `compiled` as `Element` and casting `querySelectorAll` should fix your issue?

Comment: @David Correct. It would solve the technical part of it in this context. Thankyou for your aid.

Comment: @David As long as I am the only one working with the code I alright with setting `component: Element`. But... I have a more project-y issue though and that is that my code might be copied ad verbatim by someone not delving into the problem but just being ok with copying the code. Hence I decide to leave `component: any` to code without type protection and hope for the programmer to investigate and think. But as I said... that is another problem outside of this question and even stack overflow.